# AKS http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller Port 80 is already in use

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have two AKS K8s clusters (ver 1.11.1 in West and North Europe) with http-application-routing addon enabled. Suddenly today pod named addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller-xxxx crashed and showed the state:

```
  State:        Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
  Last State:   Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    255
```

kubectl logs addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller-xxxx
shows:

```
I1003 20:21:21.129694       7 flags.go:162] Watching for ingress class: addon-http-application-routing
W1003 20:21:21.129745       7 flags.go:165] only Ingress with class "addon-http-application-routing" will be processed by this ingress controller
F1003 20:21:21.129819       7 main.go:59] Port 80 is already in use. Please check the flag --http-port
```

If I connect to any node on any cluster and check opened ports with `netstat -latun` it shows no service on 80 port. 
Node restart didn't help.

Comment: We had the same problem, we scaled the cluster down to kill the node and scaled it up again. This solved the problem.

Comment: Did the pod get updated today?

Comment: This pod is managed by Azure AKS, I can't update it.

Comment: Not much you can do then, other than opening a support ticket or follow up with them.

Comment: Please check the deployment. If the version is < 0.16.0 and has the security context described here https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.16.0 is not going to start

Comment: Yes, version of Nginx image was 0.13.0 and there was security context 

`securityContext:
    capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
        add:
        - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    # www-data -> 33
    runAsUser: 33`
but now I see in deployment that Microsoft has changed it from 0.13.0 to 0.19.0! And it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I just killed the affected node and it started working again. Here's a link where a similar solution also worked:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3177

Comment: I've cordoned, drained and restarted nodes before asking the question here - no luck,  but now I see that MS has changed the Nginx version in deployment from 0.13.0 to 0.19.0, please check Nginx version in deployment on your cluster.

Comment: I have 0.13.0 still and it's working now, but thanks for the info. Btw, I've not only restarted but removed that node entirely.